# Use NodeJS to upload file in an API call

Tags: node.js

I'm looking at using NodeJS to act as the server to build an API.

Ideally I'd love for there to be an API endpoint to send a set of information as well as a file which can be saved to the files system.

Most examples I've seen are for sending a file via a form, however I'd like to do this through a post request.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this (if it's at all possible)?

At the moment what I'd like to achieve is something along the following lines:

```
app.post('/Some/Endpoint/', controller.handleSomeEndpoint, function(request, response) {
    response.send('Finished Request');
});

exports.handleSomeEndpoint = function(request, response, next) {
    var bodyarr = []
    request.on('data', function(chunk){
      bodyarr.push(chunk);
    })
    request.on('end', function(){
      console.log( bodyarr.join('') );
    })
}
```

But the data and end never get called if I run a curl command along the lines of:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/Some/Endpoint/ -F 'test=@test_file'
```

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: A form is a POST request, when sending files.  The node side of things should not have to be any different.

Comment: But how to create a req.files without a form? Any example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer seems to be that expressJS doesn't use the same method of handling a post file as the http module in nodejs.

All that was needed was including a directory for the files to be written to:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./uploads'}));
```

Which I found here:

http://www.hacksparrow.com/handle-file-uploads-in-express-node-js.html

Comment: In this way any time I send you a file through a POST request, you'll accept it and save in your ./uploads. I don't think it is safe.

Comment: I don't think it's unsafe in the sense that it's temporary storage, not permanent which means while it's accepted, it doesn't mean it's stored permanently or use. The request should be authenticated (which in my case it is).

Comment: But how to pass a req.files if no form used? I'm trying to upload file through API only.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to avoid anonymous file uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine; it's the curl usage that's wrong.  Try this instead:

```
$ curl -X POST --data-binary @test_file http://localhost:8080
```